# What is integration of $(\sin x)^{\cos x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried taking log and exponential but farthest I could go was:
$\int e^{\cos x} + sinx .dx$

I tried manipulating the equation a bit but I couldn't go farther than :
$\int (\sqrt{1-t^2})^{t-1} .dt$

What should I do now to get the integral?

Comment: I do not think that this function has a nice antiderivate. You will need numerical methods.

Comment: In general, functions of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$, where $f$ and $g$ are both functions in terms of $x$ don't have elementary antiderivatives.